# How to create table with multiple rows and columns using only SELECT clause (i.e. using SELECT without FROM clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know that in SQL Server, one can use SELECT clause without FROM clause, and create a table with one row and one column

```
SELECT 1 AS n;
```

But I was just wondering, is it possible to use SELECT clause without FROM clause, to create

1. a table with one column and multiple rows
2. a table with multiple columns and one row
3. a table with multiple columns and multiple rows

I have tried many combinations such as

```
SELECT VALUES(1, 2) AS tableName(n, m);
```

to no success.

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I'm dont have a particular question in mind. I guess I asked the questions out of curiosity. Just want to know if it is possible, if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with CTE and using `union`(Use `union all` if you want to display duplicates)

**[Rextester Sample for all 3 scenarios](http://rextester.com/GFTTE59560)**

- One Column and multiple rows

  ```
  with tbl1(id) as
  (select 1 union all
   select 2)
  select * from tbl1;
  ```
- One row and multiple columns

  ```
  with tbl2(id,name) as
  (select 1,'A')
  select * from tbl2;
  ```
- Multiple columns and multiple rows

  ```
  with tbl3(id,name) as
  (select 1,'A' union all
  select 2,'B')
  select * from tbl3;
  ```

Comment: I was wondering, What is the need of CTE in this scenarios. Thanks.

Comment: No need as such. If you want to use the same table at multiple places in the query, then CTE is a better alternative. So for example, you can do something like `with tbl3 as .....  select * from tbl3 a1 inner join tbl3 a2 on .....` without writing the whole tbl3 query again and again.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- One column, multiple rows.
select 1 as ColumnName union all select 2; -- Without FROM;
select * from ( values ( 1 ), ( 2 ) ) as Placeholder( ColumnName ); -- With FROM.

-- Multiple columns, one row.
select 1 as TheQuestion, 42 as TheAnswer; -- Without FROM.
select * from ( values ( 1, 42 ) ) as Placeholder( TheQuestion, TheAnswer ); -- With FROM.

-- Multiple columns and multiple rows.
select 1 as TheQuestion, 42 as TheAnswer union all select 1492, 12; -- Without FROM.
select * from ( values ( 1, 2 ), ( 2, 4 ) ) as Placeholder( Column1, Column2 ); -- With FROM.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do all that by using `UNION` keyword

```
create table tablename as select 1 as n,3 as m union select 2 as n,3 as m
```

In Oracle it will be dual:

```
create table tablename as select 1 as n,3 as m from dual union select 2 as n,3 as m from dual
```

Comment: can you share an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION operator:

```
CREATE TABLE AS SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values you can use UNION ALL.
**The column names in the result-set are usually equal to the column names in the first SELECT statement in the UNION.**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
--1) a table with one column and multiple rows
select * into tmptable0 from(
select 'row1col1' as v1
union all
select 'row2col1' as v1
) tmp

--2) a table with multiple columns and one row
select  'row1col1' as v1, 'row1col2' as v2 into tmptable1

--3) a table with multiple columns and multiple rows
select * into tmptable2 from(
select 'row1col1'  as v1, 'row1col2' as v2 
union all
select 'row2col1' as v2, 'row2col2' as v2 
) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

One can create a view and later can query it whenever required

-- table with one column and multiple rows

```
create view vw1 as
(
 select 'anyvalue' as col1
 union all
 select 'anyvalue' as col1
)

select * from vw1
```

-- table with multiple columns and multiple rows

```
create view vw2 as
(
 select 'anyvalue1' as col1, 'anyvalue1' as col2
 union all 
 select 'anyvalue2' as col1, 'anyvalue2' as col2
)

select * from vw2
```